# How to binarize images in PyTorch?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch

I am trying to make a ROC curve for my Image Dataset, and for that, I need to binarize the dataset. The dataset that I am using is Retinal OCT image dataset. But I am lost when I am trying to binarize the dataset for making the ROC plot.

I am making a classifier using PyTorch for 4 classes using resnet and printing the Train and test loss along with Accuracy. But after I get to know about Confusion matrix that accuracy may not give us the proper result if we have more than two classes. Now I am calculating the Sensitivity(fpr) and Specificity(tpr) of the dataset and trying to print the ROC plot using these parameters. I am following this tutorial from Scikit-Learn to print this - 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html.
There I saw that first I have to binarize the test data, but when I try to do this, getting an error every time.

I am doing the entire program in Google Colab and this is how I am connecting my drive -

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
data = "/content/drive/My Drive/AMD_new"
```

Now I saw this code in Scikit learn's website to binarize the data -

```
# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

# Binarize the output
y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = y.shape[1]
```

This is my dataset and dataloader -

```
# choose the training and test datasets
train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data+"/train", transform=transform_train)
test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data+"/val", transform = transform_test)

test_data = label_binarize(test_data, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3])

dataloader_train = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
dataloader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32, num_workers=2)
```

When I try to binarize test_data, it is giving me this error - 
`OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BufferedReader name='/content/drive/My Drive/AMD_new/val/CNV/CNV-6294785-1.jpeg'>`

in this line `test_data = label_binarize(test_data, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3])`

Can any of you guys please guide me how can I binarize the dataset and am I going in the right direction or not in printing the ROC plot? I a pretty new to this Pytorch domain, that's why I wonder if I am going in the right way to get the ROC or not. Thanks.

Comment: Why confusion matrix might not give you the appropiate result if you have more than two clases? The confusion matrix is for n classes

Comment: As per [this post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/), I got to know that classification accuracy can be more than 80% if I have more than 2 classes(I have four classes), so I think of making a Sensitivity and Specificity calculation, and then get the ROC curve for betterment. To get the  Sensitivity and Specificity values, I used the Confusion Matrix. @BCJuan can you show a better way to calculate Sensitivity and Specificity values? Thanks.